# Retrofit - Intercept responses globally

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I'd like to intercept all responses received by the retrofit engine, and scan for HTTP error code, for example error 403.

I'm aware I can use the failure(RetrofitError error) callback of every request and check for 403's but I'd like to wrap the response globally.

I can see that request interception is possible, but I do not see a similar option for response.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I was able to accomplish that by adding an interceptor to the OkHttpClient that retrofit is using.

Kotlin + Retrofit 2.x

```
val clientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
clientBuilder.addInterceptor { chain ->
            val request = chain.request()
            val response = chain.proceed(request)
            if (response.code() == 403) {
                handleForbiddenResponse()
            }
            response
        }
```

Retrofit 2.x:

```
   OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
   clientBuilder.
            addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                   Request request = chain.request();
                   Response response = chain.proceed(request);
                   if (response.code() == 403) {
                         handleForbiddenResponse();
                   }
                   return response;
                }
            });


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(clientBuilder.build();)
            .build();
```

Retrofit 1.x:

```
public class ForbiddenInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        if (response.code() == 403) {
             handleForbiddenResponse();
        }
        return response;
    }
}



OkHttpClient okHttpClient = Utils.createUnsafeOkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new ForbiddenInterceptor());

RestAdapter.Builder restAdapterBuilder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(API_BASE_URL)
        .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient));
```

Comment: Can you explain what should I suppoded to use for ActivityFragmentInteraction

Comment: I would love to know what doStuff() might do being this is a background thread.

Comment: What is **RestAdapter**

Comment: this is retrofit 1.x, I will update the answer to retrofit 2 :)

Comment: Any way to invoke onFailure() of the Retrofit API caller? [I understand this "handling" is detached from Retrofit API call itself]

Comment: What is `handleForbiddenResponse()` and why do you think errors are not rethrown further?

Comment: Hi @Aviran, I want to call an api from interceptor whenever 401 code is received from any api response. API is not getting triggered here. Is it achievable? If so, how. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to override the `execute` method in Retrofit's `OkClient`. In my case I was looking for a specific response header, so it went something like this:

```
OkClient client = new OkClient(okHttpClient) {
    @Override
    public retrofit.client.Response execute(retrofit.client.Request request) throws IOException {
        retrofit.client.Response response = super.execute(request);

        // Do whatever with 'response', such as looking for the value of a particular header:

        List<retrofit.client.Header> headers = response.getHeaders();
        for (retrofit.client.Header header : headers) {
            if (MY_HEADER.equalsIgnoreCase(header.getName())) {
                this.savedValue = header.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
};

RestAdapter.Builder restAdapterBuilder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(API_BASE_URL)
        .setClient(client);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()  
    .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);

            // todo deal with the issues the way you need to
            if (response.code() == 500) {
                startActivity(
                        new Intent(
                                ErrorHandlingActivity.this,
                                ServerIsBrokenActivity.class
                        )
                );

                return response;
            }

            return response;
        }
    })
    .build();

Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()  
        .baseUrl("http://your_url")
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
```

As you can see in the snippet above, the `okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);` line accesses the server response. Consequently, we can check the status code with `if (response.code() == 500)` and then open the `ServerIsBrokenActivity`.