# Access Raw Response After Conversion

Tags: android, rest, gson, retrofit2, okhttp

I've a backend that returns 200 HTTP code even if the request had errors:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Generic error",
        "code": 13000
    }
}
```

Now, how can I access raw response body, after using:

```
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
```

I've tried:

```
response.raw().body().string()
```

But I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read raw response body of a converted body.
```

I've implemented a generic APICallback class, that should "block" the success and fire an APIError event:

```
abstract class APICallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    abstract void onSuccess(Call<T> call, T result);

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
        if (response.body() != null) {

            if (response.body() instanceof APIError) {
                // this is not working
            } else {
                onSuccess(call, response.body());
            }
        } else {
            apiError = new APIError("Unknown error");
            bus.post(new APIErrorEvent(apiError));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<T> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
        String message = t.getLocalizedMessage() != null ? t.getLocalizedMessage() : "Unknown error";
        apiError = new APIError(message);
        bus.post(new APIErrorEvent(apiError, source));
    }
}
```

I'd like to mantain the "auto-converter" capability...many thanks in advance.

Comment: can you print and check what `response.body` contains? Also, try `Gson` lib to convert `response.body` to  a json

Comment: I'm already using GsonConverterFactory, the response Body converted to String is the name of the model like: my.package.models.Model

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/40288164/9823185

Comment: this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294557/retrofit-intercept-responses-globally

Answer (score 2):

For error response you have to take response.errorBody() not response.body()

```
abstract class APICallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

abstract void onSuccess(Call<T> call, T result);

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
    if (response.body() != null) {

        if (response.body() instanceof APIError) {
            // this is not working
        } else {
            onSuccess(call, response.body());
        }
    } else {
        apiError = new APIError("Unknown error");
        bus.post(new APIErrorEvent(apiError));
    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<T> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
    String message = t.getLocalizedMessage() != null ? t.getLocalizedMessage() : "Unknown error";
    apiError = new APIError(message);
    bus.post(new APIErrorEvent(apiError, source));
}
}
```

change to

```
abstract class APICallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    abstract void onSuccess(Call<T> call, T result);

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                onSuccess(call, response.body());

            }
        } else {
            if (response.errorBody() != null) {

                if (response.errorBody() instanceof APIError) {

                }
            } else {
                apiError = new APIError("Unknown error");
                bus.post(new APIErrorEvent(apiError));
            }
        }

    }

@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<T> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
    String message = t.getLocalizedMessage() != null ? t.getLocalizedMessage() : "Unknown error";
    apiError = new APIError(message);
    bus.post(new APIErrorEvent(apiError, source));
}
 }
```